# ATmega2560 using UART interrupt to control global flag

Tags: c, arduino, uart, interrupt-handling, atmega

I recently met a problem when I was playing with an ATmega2560, and I really don't understand what's wrong with it.

Here is my code.

main:

```
#include "Definitions.h"

int main(void) {
    Initialization();
    while (1) {
        //_delay_ms(1); // or printf...
        //wait for RXC flag
        if (RxFlag) {
            //wait for new byte in
            //PORTB &= ~(1 << PB7);
            PORTB |= (1 << PB7);
            rxcount = 0;
            UDR0 = 'R';
            RxFlag = false;
            TxFlag = false;
        }
    }
}
```

IRQ:

```
#include "Definitions.h"

ISR(USART0_RX_vect) {
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << RXC0)))
    //wait for RXC flag
        ;
    /* Loop-back test */
    //PORTB |= (1 << PB7);
    //test_data = UDR0;
    TxFlag = true;
    //enableUDRI0();
    //PORTB &= ~(1 << PB7);
    //PORTB |= (1 << PB7);
    RxBuffer[rxcount++] = UDR0;
    if(!(rxcount < RX_BUF_SZ)) {
        //rxcount = 0;
        PORTB |= (1 << PB7);
        RxFlag = true;
    }
}

ISR(USART0_UDRE_vect) {
    while(!(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)))
    //wait for udr to be empty
        ;
    /* Loop-back test */
    UDR0 = 0x30 + rxcount;
    disableUDRI0();
}
```

The problem is, when I received some datas from USART, I tried to set a RxFlag that can active the if-statement in main loop. But it didn't work until I uncommented the function before if-statement which may be a _delay_ms() or a printf().

It makes no sense. What I remember is that I don't need those functions and it can still set the global variables to affect main loop. Or is there any detail I had missed? Please give me some clue to figure it out, I am confused.

Comment: Please post your code here and not via external links.

Comment: A while into a ISR is the worse idea...ever... I guess you copied that form a non-interrupt driven code.

Comment: Looks like there are some major missconceptions about how interrupts work. And there is code missing. Read [ask] and follow the advice!

Comment: @MichaelWalz Sorry about that , I am new to here and feel a little nervous with how to explain what I've encountered. I'll do better next time. Thanks.

Comment: @LPs Yes, I do misunderstood about example code which is non-interrupt driven.... Thanks for the opinion!

Comment: @Olaf I apologize for my bad skill of asking, and thanks for the advice. Could you please tell me where should I start to re-build the concept about how interrupt work?

Comment: No single advice. But learn, read databooks and reference manual (or whatever that are called) and some basic books. You can't learn this is one day, week or one year.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to be definite, however I think this explains your problem so it may well be the error.

You don't include the declaration of `RXFlag`, but I surmise that you are not declaring it `volatile`. Unless you do so the compiler is allowed to assume that it knows everything about what will happen to that variable. In particular it knows that, unless `main()` calls any other functions, the value of RxFlag is never going to change. So it can optimise the `if` expression by moving it outside the loop. In effect it's changing your code like this:

```
#include "Definitions.h"

int main(void)
{
    register bool x;

    Initialization();

    x = RxFlag;

    while (1) 
    {
        //wait for RXC flag
        if (x) //wait for new byte in
        {
            //PORTB &= ~(1 << PB7);
            PORTB |= (1 << PB7);
            rxcount = 0;
            UDR0 = 'R';
            RxFlag = false;
            TxFlag = false;

        }
    }
}
```

However, if `main()` calls another function, then the compiler gives up trying to keep RxFlag in a register over that call. The other function might change the register that RxFlag is being held in. It would have to push it onto the stack or something. Reading it again is cheaper in code and time and therefore it will read it each time it goes around the loop.

The correct fix for this bug is to declare any variables that are shared between the main thread and the ISR as `volatile`.

Comment: With gcc, half of the AVR registers are *callee-saved*. And gcc makes use of that when optimizing and may keep values in registers even across function calls. A function call may also be inlined, so that, to the optimizer, it doesn't even occur as a call.